# Good places to go potholing in the UK

Tags: uk, caving

A long time ago when I was about 10 I went potholing on a school trip in Devon, and despite mild claustrophobia I found myself eventually enjoying it - egged on brilliantly by my friends. I hadn't thought about it in years until recently and now I'm curious, as a beginner:

Where are good places in the UK to go potholing^, either experienced, or with a group for training?

^*caving / spelunking*

Comment: I would imagine [PaulLydon](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/3061/paul-lydon) is the man for this

Comment: Just wondering, why was my question about "good" trips in Switzerland put on hold while this one isn't? So that I may learn to ask more properly. Thanks

Comment: I don't know, when you type a question the site asks you to be specific, and I have been told explicitly in the comment to edit the question so to be more specific, and thus, less general. This is quite odd. :)

Comment: I have no idea :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main areas for caving in the UK are:

- The Yorkshire Dales
- The Peak District
- South Wales
- The Mendip Hills (near Bristol)
- The North Pennines

There are other, smaller areas as well, such as: Forest of Dean, Devon, Barrow in Furness, Assynt (in Scotland).

[The UK Caving WIKI](http://ukcaving.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) has some more information on this.

If you would like to get back into caving, the best bet is to join a caving club.

The British Caving Association's [Try Caving](http://www.trycaving.org.uk/) website is a very good resource for beginners.

Go on, give it a go! Not all caves are small! For example, near me in the Peak District:

[image: Titan, a shaft in Peak cavern near Castleton, by Robbie Shone]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [Mendips](https://www.google.com/search?q=Mendips&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab) with an organised group.  Could do a morning session in the dry [Goatchurch Cavern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goatchurch_Cavern) and an afternoon session in the wet but superb [Swildon's Hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swildon%27s_Hole).  Around there there's loads of other places including [Sidcot Swallet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidcot_Swallet) with the well-named Lobster Pot (easy to go in and a struggle to get out!).

There are lots of organised companies doing those trips.  I've used http://www.caveclimb.com/ who provided excellent guide/instructors.  Obviously there's loads of other similar companies.